Umbraco V14 to V15 Timeout on Blocklist Migration
I'm using version 14.3.1 and migrating to V15 but I'm not able to migrate 3 BlockList components.
Log:
Execute ConvertBlockListEditorProperties      Migration starting for all properties of type: Umbraco.BlockList      starting property type 1/19 : Hero Banners (id: 59, alias: heroBanners)...      finíshed 100 of 245 properties      finíshed 200 of 245 properties     245 properties converted, saving...     starting property type 2/19 : Alert Banners (id: 78, alias: bannersAlert)...     7 properties converted, saving...      starting property type 3/19 : Header Links (id: 140, alias: headerLinks)... [17:03:54 ERR] Exception (70050326). Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.  ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action

1 wrapCloseInAction)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action
1 wrapCloseInAction)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, SqlCommand command, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource

1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at StackExchange.Profiling.Data.ProfiledDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in C:\projects\dotnet\src\MiniProfiler.Shared\Data\ProfiledDbCommand.cs:line 204
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.FaultHandling.FaultHandlingDbCommand.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<ExecuteDbDataReader>b__0()
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.FaultHandling.FaultHandlingDbCommand.<>c__DisplayClass38_01.<Execute>b__0()    at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.FaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[TResult](Func1 func)
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.FaultHandling.FaultHandlingDbCommand.Execute[T](Func1 f)    at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.FaultHandling.FaultHandlingDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)    at NPoco.Database.<>c__DisplayClass298_0.<ExecuteReaderHelper>b__0()    at NPoco.Database.ExecutionHook[T](Func1 action)
at NPoco.Database.ExecuteReaderHelper(DbCommand cmd)
at NPoco.Database.ExecuteDataReader(DbCommand cmd, Boolean sync)
at NPoco.AsyncHelper.RunSync[T](Task1 task)    at NPoco.Database.QueryImp[T](T instance, Expression1 listExpression, Func2 idFunc, Sql Sql, PocoData pocoData)+MoveNext()    at System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
at NPoco.Database.Fetch[T](Sql sql)
at Umbraco.Extensions.NPocoDatabaseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass13_02.<FetchByGroups>b__0(IEnumerable1 x)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.IEnumerableSelectIterator2.MoveNext()    at Umbraco.Extensions.EnumerableExtensions.SelectByGroups[TResult,TSource](IEnumerable1 source, Func2 selector, Int32 groupSize)+MoveNext()    at System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.ContentRepositoryBase3.GetPropertyCollections[T](List1 temps)
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.DocumentRepository.MapDtoToContent(DocumentDto dto)
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.DocumentRepository.ContentByGuidReadRepository.PerformGet(Guid id)
at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Cache.DefaultRepositoryCachePolicy2.Get(TId id, Func2 performGet, Func2 performGetAll)    at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.EntityRepositoryBase2.Get(TId id)
at Umbraco.Cms.Infrastructure.Persistence.Repositories.Implement.DocumentRepository.Get(Guid id)
at Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services.ContentService.GetById(Guid key)
at Umbraco.Cms.Core.PropertyEditors.MultiUrlPickerValueEditor.ToEditor(IProperty property, String culture, String segment)
ClientConnectionId:e40e2bfb-357d-4c06-8848-fd48498ab6c5`
Component image
I've already set the DB timeout to more than 1 hour and it doesn't go beyond that point, it only advances to the next step when I remove the component from the project.
Does anyone have any ideas? I've already cleaned up the history to minimize the amount of data in the conversion as well.
Thanks
